# redmine stopping after explicit exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, bluehost

I installed the application Redmine (Ruby on rails application) on my bluehost hosting plan, but this is very slow in the first interaction, which makes it very difficult to use.

I went to investigate and noticed that is stopping the process of redmine after a few seconds of interaction.
My fastcgi.crash.log also fills up with:

```
...
[26/Feb/2012:18:11:33 :: 1674] starting
[26/Feb/2012:18:12:19 :: 1674] asked to stop immediately
[26/Feb/2012:18:12:19 :: 1674] stopping after explicit exit
[26/Feb/2012:18:49:43 :: 28395] starting
[26/Feb/2012:18:50:34 :: 28395] asked to stop immediately
[26/Feb/2012:18:50:34 :: 28395] stopping after explicit exit
[26/Feb/2012:18:52:36 :: 2427] starting
[26/Feb/2012:18:53:28 :: 2427] asked to stop immediately
[26/Feb/2012:18:53:28 :: 2427] stopping after explicit exit
[26/Feb/2012:19:09:49 :: 20895] starting
[26/Feb/2012:19:10:29 :: 20895] asked to stop immediately
[26/Feb/2012:19:10:29 :: 20895] stopping after explicit exit
```

is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: How did you go about installing it?  Have you installed working Rails apps on Bluehost before?  Have you checked their documentation or technical support?

Comment: thx for responsing. was the first time I installed a ruby on rails app in my life.
follow the official documentation for this application: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

already contacted the support of bluehost, but said they found no problem in the host.

Comment: Do you have to use Bluehost, or would you consider another provider (that would make it easier)?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is:  is this for practice with Rails, or do you currently have a website on bluehost and you need this Rails application to work with what's currently on bluehost?

Comment: I needed this application and bluehost only have available to install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, with redmine 1.2.x and 1.3.x on my VPS running ubuntu 10.04.
For some reason fastcgi killed apache.

What I ended up doing was, remove fastcgi and reconfigure my virtual host using passenger.
I used this tutorial
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_with_Ruby-on-Rails_and_Apache2-Passenger
which worked perfect apart from the path to the gems being slightly different:

use /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
instead of 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.14/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the situation, I think I may have a solution for you.

If this is your first time deploying a Rails app, I would definitely recommend using [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Here is a free Rails tutorial, and if you follow the first chapter it will show you exactly how to set up a Rails app for the first time and deploy it to version control at GitHub, and then to production on Heroku:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Once you understand how to do that, you can use this GitHub repo of Redmine:  https://github.com/edavis10/redmine

You'll need to clone this repository to your machine, then you can push it to your GitHub account and then push it to Heroku - just like you did in the tutorial.

It may sound a little complicated at first, but once you get it you'll find it very easy to deploy a rails app.

I love Heroku - beginners and pro's use it all the time.  There are tons of professional sites hosted there.  Also, it's free for small sites.

There are other Ruby on Rails hosting sites too - [Engine Yard](http://www.engineyard.com/) is another good one.

This doesn't directly fix the problem that you are having with Bluehost - I'm assuming that you will require some extra steps to get it configured there - but Heroku will make life with Rails much easier.